# Function call crash fixed by print statements

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am compiling a Fortran program on windows with visual studio 2012 and intel fortran 2013. In the program, I call a C function which is part of a static library:

```
call myfunction(arg1,arg2,...);
```

When I run in debug mode, everything is fine. When I run it in release mode, the program crashes during that function call (I test it by printing to the screen before/after the call) with the following error:

```
forrtl: severe (157): Program Exception - access violation
```

Now the interesting part, if I add print statements after and before the call as follows

```
print 'Calling myfunction'
call myfunction(arg1,arg2,...);
print 'myfunction finished'
```

the program runs perfectly in release mode. If I remove either one of the print statements (or both), I get the above error!

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on here?

**More information:**

The function declaration in Fortran is:

```
!DEC$ ALIAS  myfunction, 'myfunction'
```

The function declaration in C is:

```
extern "C" void myfunction(double *arg1, double *arg2, ...)
```

Comment: pls improve the question title

Comment: 1) Is it a vararg function? 2) How have you declared myfunction in Fortran? 3) How has myfunction been declared in C - __stdcall or __cdecl?

Comment: Sorry, but what is a vararg function?

Comment: Sorry, you are changing it piece by piece. Just show the ACTUAL code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common symptom of a stack corruption. Probably, you are calling `myfunction` with wrong arguments, but it can be somewhere deeper inside it. Check every call around and check the types of all arguments.

Be sure to use `-check all` and `-warn  all` with ifort when debugging. That includes `-warn interfaces` which is very helpful in similar problems, but because you are calling a C function it will probably not find the cause here.

**EDIT - for 2 argument subroutine:**

In your case make sure both arguments are `double precision` or `c_double` or `real*8` depending on which type of declaration you use. Don't put any third argument there, as your first piece of code might suggest!

The modern way of interfacing this in `Fortran 2003` would be:

```
interface
  subroutine myfunction(arg1, arg2) bind(C, name="myfunction")
    use iso_c_binding
    real(c_double) :: arg1, arg2
  end subroutine
end interface
```

which is put instead of the older (and optional) `external myfunction` in the declaration part of your code.

In any case, carefully check the types and correct position of all the arguments, whatever the final number of them is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the ... is only to indicate that I actually have more arguments than 2 (it has 10 arguments, a mix of integers and reals)

Comment: I guess this will indeed teach me to put the actual code as you say, a colleague updated the C library and added an argument to the function definition...that explains my problem. Thanks for your help.